# How do I align an equation array in Microsoft Office OneNote 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

I am trying to align an equation array to the character "=" in Microsoft Office OneNote 2013. In Word, I do this by right clicking and selecting the "Align at this Character" option. However, this option is non-existent in OneNote. Does anyone know how to do this in OneNote? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An equation array can be aligned in Microsoft OneNote 2013 by adding an "&"  before the alignment character and then changing the equation to professional.